# Taking power of a simple function with disjoint domains

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question in mind:

Suppose I have a nonnegative simple function 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}{a_i}{\chi_{E_i}}$$ where the $E_i$s are pairwise disjoint.

Then consider $$(\sum_{i=1}^{N}{a_i}{\chi_{E_i}})^p$$ where $1<p<\infty$.

Is it true that $$(\sum_{i=1}^{N}{a_i}{\chi_{E_i}})^p=\sum_{i=1}^{N}{{a_i}^p}{\chi_{E_i}}$$?

If yes, is it due to the pairwise disjoint $E_i$s involved?

If no, kindly provide a counterexample.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and it is due to the pairwise disjoint $E_i$.

Suppose $E_1=[0,2]$ and $E_2=[1,3]$. Let $f=2\chi_{E_1}+3\chi_{E_2}$. Then $f(1)^2=25$, since $f(1)=5$. But if we assume $f(1)^2=2^2\chi_{E_1}+3^2\chi_{E_2}$, we get $13$. This is because the sum of squares is not the square of the sum.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the prompt reply. What you mean is, for simple functions with disjoint sets, the power of the function is the sum of the power?

Comment: When the sets are disjoint, you don't have the power of the sum, since the value at each point is determined by at most one item in the sum $a_i\chi_i$.

Another way to look at this is, taking the power $(\chi_1+\chi_2)^2$ where these are characteristic functions of disjoint sets, we get $\chi_1^2+2\chi_1\chi_2+\chi_2^2$. 

$\chi_1\chi_2$ will always be $0$, since there are no $x$ in both sets.

Comment: Oh ok. But the summation formula that is posted, the equality does hold for disjoint sets?

Comment: Your explanation is clear. Thank you very much.